# "Less than savoury" definition

Tags: meaning

Could someone say what "less than savory" means in general and in the context below?

> "Anybody who was anti-communist in the Far East was likely to receive American backing – regardless of their less than savoury background." [link](https://www.historylearningsite.co.uk/vietnam-war/the-causes-of-the-vietnam-war/)

Answer (score 1):

less than savory = unsavory, an antonym of savory

adjective: [unsavory](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/unsavory)

> ˌənˈsāv(ə)rē/
>
> disagreeable and unpleasant because morally disreputable.
>   "an unsavory reputation"
>   synonyms:   disreputable, unpleasant, undesirable

With the definition of unsavory I have inserted a simple meaning in place of the phrase in your quote:

> Diem hated all that communism stood for. This is why he got America’s
>   support – he had a poor record on human rights but his rule was in the
>   era of the “Domino Theory” and anybody who was anti-communist in the
>   Far East was likely to receive American backing – regardless of their
>   **past misdeeds**.
>    [Causes of Viet Nam War](https://www.historylearningsite.co.uk/vietnam-war/the-causes-of-the-vietnam-war/)

Comment: Thanks Ibf! It helped a lot! I cannot upvote since I only have 4 points. Bjt you taught me a new word 

Comment: a pleasure to help